# ¿Como actualizar una lista desde otra clase? - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, listview

Soy nuevo en Xamarin Forms y ya llevo varios dias sin encontrar una solucion, por favor necesito que me ayuden, tengo un Flyout en donde su menu es una clase llamada MenuPage y esta clase tiene un ListView que es el menu del Flyout, necesito que esta lista se pueda actualizar desde otra clase, el menu originalmente esta compuesto por:

- Pagina de Inicio
- Perfil de Usuario
- Carnet Virtual
- Cerrar Sesión

A esta lista necesito agregar o eliminar una opcion que es `UProyecto`, todo depende de la interaccion del usuario, tengo un formulario en donde el usuario se registra para participar de la opcion UProyecto, una vez que se registre la opcion UProyecto debe aparecer y tengo otro formulario que es para desvincularse de la opcion UProyecto y cuando el usuario se desvincule, la opcion UProyecto debe desaparecer. Quiero mencionar que la aplicacion no la hice yo, esta opcion de UProyecto es un nuevo modulo que me asignaron en mi trabajo para que la incorpere a la aplicacion y aveces entender la logica de otro progrador puede ser un poco desafiante. Les comparto el codigo:

Primeramente, ni bien el usuario inicia sesion se llama a la pagina de inicio que contiene el Flyout.

**MasterPage.xaml:**

```
<FlyoutPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CPSiuMovil.Pages.Autenticar.MasterPage"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:CPSiuMovil.Pages.Autenticar">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <pages:MenuPage />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>

    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator" BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainColor}" BarTextColor="{StaticResource MenuFontColorWhite}">
          <x:Arguments>
            <pages:MainPage />
          </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

Luego tenemos el MenuPage:

**MenuPage.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CPSiuMovil.Pages.Autenticar.MenuPage"
    Title="Menú"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MenuColor}"
    BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin">
    <ContentPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Color="White" Glyph="&#xf0C9;" />
    </ContentPage.IconImageSource>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='0,70,0,10', Android='0,10,0,10'}">
            <controls:CircleImage x:Name="imgFoto" BorderColor="White" BorderThickness="3" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" />
            <Label x:Name="txbNombreCompleto" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Label x:Name="txbNombreCarrera" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="lvMenuLateral" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainColor}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="0,20,0,0">
                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image WidthRequest="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Color="White" Glyph="{Binding Icon}" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MenuPage.cs:**

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{

    #region Attributes and Properties

    NavigationServices navigationServices;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            navigationServices = new NavigationServices();
            txbNombreCompleto.Text = App.NombreEstudiante;
            txbNombreCarrera.Text = App.eCarreraSimple.Nom_Car;
            imgFoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("IconPerfil.png");
            if (App.Fotografia != null)
            {
                if (App.Fotografia.Length > 0)
                {
                    ImageSource image = ImagenDesdeBD(App.Fotografia);
                    imgFoto.Source = image;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Atención", "No tienes conexión a internet", "Aceptar");
            return;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Metodos Protegidos

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        CargarMenuLateral();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Method

    private ImageSource ImagenDesdeBD(byte[] imagen)
    {
        ImageSource newImage = null;
        newImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imagen));
        return newImage;
    }

    private void CargarMenuLateral()
    {
        ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> ListaMenu = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel()
            {
                Icon = FontAwesomeIcons.House,
                Title = "Página de inicio",
                PageName = "MainPage"
            },
            new MenuItemViewModel()
            {
                Icon = FontAwesomeIcons.User,
                Title = "Perfil de Usuario",
                PageName = "SettingsPage"
            },
            new MenuItemViewModel()
            {
                Icon = FontAwesomeIcons.AddressCard,
                Title = "Carnet Virtual",
                PageName = "CarnetVirtualPage"
            },
        };

        if (App.EsPostulado)
        {
            ListaMenu.Add(new MenuItemViewModel()
            {
                Icon = FontAwesomeIcons.ListCheck,
                Title = "UProyecto",
                PageName = "UProyectoPage"
            });
        }

        ListaMenu.Add(new MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            Icon = FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowRightFromBracket,
            Title = "Cerrar sesión",
            PageName = "CloseSession"
        });

        lvMenuLateral.ItemsSource = ListaMenu;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Luego tenemos la clase MenuItemViewModel:

**MenuItemViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{

    #region Attributes and Properties

    private NavigationServices navigationServices;

    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public MenuItemViewModel()
    {
        navigationServices = new NavigationServices();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Method

    public ICommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(() => navigationServices.Navigate(PageName)); }
    }

    public ICommand NavigateMainPageCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(() => navigationServices.NavigateMainPage(PageName)); }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Y por ultimo, la case NavigationService:

**NavigationService.cs:**

```
public class NavigationServices
{

    #region Constructor

    public NavigationServices()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Metodos Publicos

    public async void Navigate(string PageName)
    {
        App.Master.IsPresented = false;
        switch (PageName)
        {
            case "SettingsPage":
                await NavigateMainPage(new SettingPage());
                break;
            case "CarnetVirtualPage":
                await NavigateMainPage(new CarnetVirtualPage());
                break;
            case "UProyectoPage":
                await NavigateMainPage(new UProyectoPage());
                break;
            case "CloseSession":
                var task = Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("Cerrar sesión", "¿Estás seguro que deseas cerrar sesión?", "Si", "No");
                if (task == null)
                    return;

                var result = await task;
                if (result)
                {
                    Preferences.Clear();
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public async void NavigateMainPage(string PageName)
    {
        switch (PageName)
        {

            #region Recursos

            case "UProyectoRegistrarParticipacionPage":
                await NavigateMainPage(new UProyectoRegistrarParticipacionPage());
                break;

            #endregion

            #region Perfil

            case "EditarDatosContactoPage":
                await NavigateMainPage(new EditarDatosContactoPage());
                break;

            #endregion

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Metodos Internos

    internal void SetMainPage(string pageName)
    {
        switch (pageName)
        {
            case "MasterPage":
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterPage();
                break;
            case "LoginPage":
                Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
                break;
            case "NotInternet":
                Application.Current.MainPage = new NoConnectionInternetPage();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Metodos Privados

    private static async Task Navigate<T>(T page) where T : Page
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(page, "Atrás");
        await App.Navigator.PushAsync(page);
    }

    private static async Task NavigateMainPage<T>(T page) where T : Page
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, true);
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(page, "Atrás");
        await App.Navigator.PushAsync(page);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Si necesitan algun otro codigo me avisan por favor, estare al pendiente de cualquier comentario. Gracias.

Comment: A mi todos los nombres de variables y esas cosas, no me dicen absolutamente nada. Por favor, señala claramente donde estas creando el menu y donde queres agregar la opcion...

Comment: En la clase MenuPage.cs hay un metodo denominado CargarMenuLateral(), ahi se esta creando y en esa misma lista se tiene que agregar o eliminar la nueva opcion.

Comment: Pues, yo lo veo simple.. en lugar de crearlo ahi, usa un VM para el menu, que englobe la lista, y solo pasa ese VM a la pantalla, de forma tal que lo puedas mandar a otras... es refactorizar con ganas, pero no es algo complicado...

Comment: Como soy nuevo en Xamarin Forms todavia no entiendo varias cosas, pero en base a lo que mencionaste tratare de adecuarlo.

Comment: esto lvMenuLateral.ItemsSource = ListaMenu;
 puede tranquilamente venir de una clase... y si esa clase la compartis, teoricamente como es una observablecollection, deberias poder hacerle cambios y que cambie el menu...